# Delphi: TOpenDialog + VCL Styles corrupts filenames with large amount of files

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

Using Delphi Seattle in W7 x64. When using a custom VCL style and you select a large amount of files (like 2-3k+), the filenames are corrupted. Without a custom style this doesn't happen.

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles;

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Onyx Blue');
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var s: string;
   ts: TStringList;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    ts := TStringList.Create;
    for s in OpenDialog1.Files do
     ts.Add(s);
  end else Exit;
  ts.SaveToFile('z:\files.txt');
  ts.Free;
end;

object OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog
  Filter = 'Pictures (jpg,png,bmp,gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif|All Files|*.*'
  Options = [ofReadOnly, ofAllowMultiSelect, ofEnableSizing, ofForceShowHidden]
  Title = 'Select files to upload'
  Left = 201
  Top = 64
end
```

On my end, this code results in only 769 files written to the log out of ~5000, and their initial path "z:" gets corrupted with other characters "?"

Any way to fix this?

Note: the new TFileOpenDialog does not seem to have this issue, however it does bring others as shown here: (besides being Vista+)

[image]
[image]

Comment: And if you would not use custom VCL style - it would be different ?

Comment: Works fine without the custom style.

Comment: My bet is then without custom styles the dialog goes into standard Windows Vista+ API call path, and like `TFileOpenDialog` manages to do it. But with non-standard VCL styles it has to override default Windows style and falls to limited pre-Vista modes. Try to install Windows 2000/XP and try the program there even without styles. Chances are it will only work with Vista+ anyway, so you would have no reason to avoid using `TFileOpenDialog`

Comment: *Works fine without the custom style* - Apparently not, according to the MS link that @Arioch'The posted in the answer below.

Comment: It does in my testing, maybe it was fixed since that report? (almost 6 years old)

Comment: As a follow-up, what kind of UI needs to allow the user to select that many individual files at once, rather than selecting folders full of files?

Comment: This is wrong, anyway. I just tested with the identical configuration of the OpenDialog, adding the filenames to a TMemo, and selected 2108 image files from a folder I created to hold them temporarily, and all 2108 display properly in that memo after navigating to the folder, hitting Ctrl+A to select all files, and then clicking OK on the dialog. I'm using the same Onyx Blue style you indicated, Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1, on Win7 64 bit. I can post the code if you want to see it.

Comment: It seems to be a buffer issue either way. I just tried with 2000 files, same problem, however.. the filenames were quite long. Did the same test after renaming the files to a much shorter name like a0001 a0002 etc, and like that it worked fine.

Comment: "what kind of UI needs", specifically it's an imgur uploader, a user messaged me to report the issue when he selected more than 2k files to be uploaded to an album. So while this does seem a little extreme case, it does happen, there is no reason why he shouldn't be allowed to do that, so what are we supposed to do in such case? you can't even check for the amount of files selected as Files.Count already is wrong after the Execute call. As for SelectFolder, heh, have you tried that with VCL styles? the scrollbars don't work then.

Comment: for such a huge file lists I suggest your customer select the files in regular Windows Explorer window and then use r-click context menu to send them to your application, like it is implemented in http://zenden.ws/ru/imageuploader

Comment: Personally I se no point in using VCL styles. I think user should be able to select different styles for different programs on his own discretion... Anyway I think you may find a lot of skins/themes components on www.torry.net and give them a run, perhaps they would do better

Comment: Delphi is indeed trying to make new life with LLVM and FMX so I indeed see little sense in upgrading if you develop plain old Windows applications. Maybe XE6, there were good reviews... But personally I am using XE2 and do not plan to move.

Comment: Also files uploader seems to be a relatively simple app. Try your chances with CodeTyphon/Lazarus. Abandoning WinGDIU and enforcing your app to use GTX or Qt you would probably bystep Windows Common Dialogs API and its limitation. The challenges though would be adapting GTX/Qt skins for Windows platform and purchasing Qt lib commercial license for non-FLOSS development (dunno if that is even possible with GTX)

Comment: Are you using the new common file item dialog or the old common dialogs. The latter force the caller to supply a fixed size buffer before the user selects files. That would explain the problem.

Comment: Old one, but new one comes with other issues.

Comment: Old dialigs have known limitations. That you have encountered. Use new dialogs. Or use old with larger buffer.

Comment: "use old with larger buffer" how? Noticed a question you answered where you mentioned modifying the VCL for this, could you share?

Comment: That just pushes the problem further away. The right solution is to use new vista dialogs.

Comment: New dialogs are messed up while custom VCL styles as already explained. RRUZ fix works though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experimenting this behavior because the size of the buffer passed to the [Classic Open Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the results of the selected file(s), the buffer is represented by the `lpstrFile` element which is part of the [`OPENFILENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. The VCL internally set the size of this buffer to `High(Word) - 16` (65519) bytes when the multi-select option is enabled and a `MAX_PATH` buffer size when the single file selection is enabled.

This is part of the VCL code (Vcl.Dialogs) which show this

```
function TOpenDialog.DoExecute(Func: Pointer; ParentWnd: HWND): Bool;
const
  MultiSelectBufferSize = High(Word) - 16;
...
...
    if ofAllowMultiSelect in FOptions then
      nMaxFile := MultiSelectBufferSize else
      nMaxFile := MAX_PATH;
    SetLength(TempFilename, nMaxFile + 2);
    lpstrFile := PChar(TempFilename);
...
...
```

Starting with Windows Vista and the introduction of the New Dialogs [(`IFileOpenDialog`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834(v=vs.85).aspx), the selected files are returned by the  [`IFileOpenDialog::GetResults`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775831(v=vs.85).aspx) method in a [`IShellItemArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761106(v=vs.85).aspx), So the buffer limitation doesn't apply.

In summary this behavior **is not caused by the VCL Styles**.

Finally if you want use the modern dialogs with a custom style try the [VCL Styles Utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils) project.

[image]

Comment: U seem to like styles. Can u be the one maintaining them for Virtual Tree View ?

Comment: Thanks, your fix works with the new dialogs, they were all messed up otherwise. The issue with old ones is not caused directly by the VCL, but it does happen as detailed in the question, somehow the buffer is exhausted earlier in such case for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

That is not about Delphi it seems.
Just five seconds in Google and we have this:

" File Open dialog cannot return more than 1000 files "

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/shameful-limitation-file-open-dialog-cannot-return/bfff43fc-0da5-48d6-8703-dc0eac3c7581?auth=1

Comment: It doesn't happen without custom VCL styles though, I'm able to select even more than 5K then. Maybe it was fixed since that ~6y old report.

Comment: You did not said about your OS. I still think you should try it in win2000 and in xp. Or otherwise you should switch to vista+ dialogs

Comment: Vista+ dialogs with VCL styles are messed up though, check the screenshots.

Comment: @hikari, The [VCL Styles Utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils)  add support for the modern dialogs when a custom style is active.

Comment: @RRUZ awesome, thank you! new dialogs working great now. Post this as an answer and I'll accept.